# When writing TypeScript in Sublime the autocompletion doesn't add brackets

Tags: autocomplete, typescript, sublimetext3

When I write TypeScript in SublimeText and I let Sublime autocomplete a method, Sublime doesn't add the brackets.

For example when I write:

```
this.
```

And I let the autocomplete do his work, I get:

```
this.getHeroes
```

Instead of:

```
this.getHeroes()
```

I have been searching for a solution but this seems like default behavior that can't be adjusted. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone found a solution for this

Does not exist. You will have to write your own.

Note that its not trivial because autocomplete generally only inserts text. If you want to get `this.getHeroes()` you would probably need to move the cursor too `this.getHeroes(/*here*/)`. Also think you want to give this function to someone e.g `setTimeout(this.getHeroes)` you probably didn't mean to *call* the function but just want a function reference.